# How to make a matrix with \llfloor and \rrfloor and how to make smaller distance between two curly brackets?

Tags: matrices, brackets

I am working on brackets.

**1)** I want to make a smaller distance between curly brackets like this `$\{\!\!\{A, B\}\!\!\}$` in equation

`\begin{equation} \left\{\left\{\begin{array}{l} A \\ B \end{array}\right\}\right\} \end{equation}`.

[image: The size problem.]

I am using package `stmaryrd`.

How can I do this?

**2)** Also, I would like to make matrices with brackets `llfloor`, `rrfloor` and `llceil`, `rrceil`:

`$\left\llfloor \begin{matrix} A \\ B \end{matrix} \right\rrfloor$` and

`$\left\llceil \begin{matrix} A \\ B \end{matrix} \right\rrceil$`,

but the problem is that both brackets are smaller than A and B in column.

[image: The problem with brackets.]

With non-double floor and ceiling, it is in the same lenght:

[image: The problem with brackets.]

Here is the full document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{amscd}

\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\newcommand{\bbrack}[1]{
    \left\llbracket \begin{matrix} #1 \end{matrix} \right\rrbracket}
\newenvironment{bbsmallmatrix}{ 
    \left\llbracket\begin{smallmatrix}}{
    \end{smallmatrix}\right\rrbracket}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation} 
        \bbrack{ A\\ B}
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
        \left.\llfloor \begin{matrix} A \\ B \\ \end{matrix} \right.\rrfloor
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
        \left\lfloor \begin{matrix}  A \\ B    \\ \end{matrix} \right\rfloor 
    \end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\left\{\left\{\begin{array}{l}
    A \\
    B
\end{array}\right\}\right\}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

What can I do?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: please provide an example that reproduces the error, not disconnected fragments. You can only use a command with `\left` if it is declared as a character defined as extensible in the font. so it depends how you have defined `\llfloor`

Comment: I have managed to fix the error problem by putting . before \llceil or \rrceil. But LaTeX still generates the brackets smaller than A and B (I have added a print screen to my question).

Comment: putting . is same as removing `\left` (but with worse spacing)`

Comment: you still have not provided a test document, I don't know of any font with an extendable  character |⌊

Comment: Thank you. I am glad that the error porblem is fixed. Do you know what to do to make floor and ceil on both sides the same lenght as A and B in column? With non-dobule floor and ceil it is the same lenght (I have also added a picture to compare). Thanks a lot.

Comment: You _still_ have shown no example document, and your code in 2 will give an error so not the output you show, except accidental error recovery

Comment: Now I have added the document.

Comment: `\left.\llfloor`  is simply wrong, use `\llfloor`

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. Do you know what to do to reduce the distance between the curly brackets on both sides of the equation (4) in the document (I have added a picture too).

Comment: exactly as I show in my answer `\left\{\!\left\{` adjust the spacing as needed

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It's working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$\left\lfloor\!\!\!\left\lfloor\!
\begin{matrix}
  1\\2\\3
\end{matrix}
\!\right\rfloor\!\!\!\right\rfloor
$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!